# Grep for an url with regexp

Tags: regex, url, grep

I need to extract these urls from a file: http://d3tlpa9bezjl6p.cloudfront.net/products/43dir/4373/full_21905_front.jpg.  I need to use regexp so I can get all the differnet urls.  This code does not work:

grep -o 'http://d3tlpa9bezjl6p.cloudfront.net/products/*.jpg'

I need to get all the jpg urls after products/ any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also note that I do have the file after the expression, just forgot to add it to my example.

Comment: I got it to work with this code: grep -Eo 'http://d3tlpa9bezjl6p.cloudfront.net/products/[[:alnum:]_]*/[[:alnum:]_]*/[[:alnum:]_]*.jpg' cat.txt

Comment: Then post it as an answer :)